# Jmeter - Is it worth performance testing a page with embedded resources enabled

Tags: html, performance, jmeter, performance-testing, embedded-resource

I have gone through few websites and of course BlazeMeter to learn how can i download embedded resources as well along with the main request of a page.

My question as stated ,is it worth performance testing along with page resources.

**assumption:
End User wont clear cache before the second and further iteration of any page.Application that needs performance test should obviously be experiencing high load and during this time its unlikely that end user clear cache each time.**

So since for the second iteration and further page resources are taken from the cache stored at client side is it worth downloading embedded resources as it wont performance test the server side behavior.

As i know Jmeter does not parse html and execute Java script and hence other resources called by this JS.

Please Correct me if I'm wrong in my above understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one "golden rule": JMeter test should represent real-life application usage, in your case each JMeter thread (virtual user) needs to [behave like a real user using the real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser).

Real browsers:

1. Download embedded resources from websites using 6 concurrent threads (per domain) for retrieving images, scripts, styles, sounds, etc.
2. Respect [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) headers when it comes to subsequent requests (in general it means that browsers download resources only once)

Coming back to your question:

1. Yes "it worth performance testing along with page resources." as long as **they belong to the application you're testing**, 3rd-party banners, styles, scripts, etc. which don't originate from your application should be excluded
2. Make sure to add [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to represent the browser cache